# create an installer for windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, installation, j9

I have developed an application using J9 that runs in windows mobile. but now I want it to package in a single installer(.cab), that should copy the J9 files, my application and its dependencies to a folder in the mobile, and creates some shortcuts(.lnk) files.
Any suggested tool that I can use to create the cab file??
Thanks!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574839/vs2008-windows-mobile-installer-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons I didn't want to go to the visual studio is because I mainly develop in linux. Never though there was a linux application to create .cab files, but there is one, it is called lcab, and the other is pocketpc-cab, I think the second uses the first one but Im not sure. Anyway I create my cab file using the second tool and tested in windows mobile and it works. I got all that I need it without having to install a whole SDK, and even better without changing to any other OS, I definitely have to love linux and its community.

Comment: cabwiz is the easiest option. but i'm guessing that if you're developing in java for windows mobile from nix, then you probably hate 'easy'.

Answer (score 2):

The correct (and likely only) tool for the job is [cabwiz.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa448616.aspx).  It's shipped as part of all of the WinMo SDKs as well as Visual Studio.  I'm not aware of any separate download for it.  There are some separate third party tool, like [cab-o-matic](http://www.phelios.net/cabomatic.html), but be aware that all of these tools simply "wrap" cabwiz.exe underneath, so you still need it.

cabwiz is pretty well [documented online in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms924762.aspx), and there are several [tutorials](http://www.nsbasic.com/ce/info/technotes/TN30b.htm) from [third parties](http://www.hjgode.de/dev/imec/Making%20a%20CAB%20file.htm) as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer... I was hoping something different from this, cause we are developing in Java and I'm not used to any of the visual studio tools, and we don't have a license. I hope somebody comes with other idea to avoid to purchase a license of a whole suite just to create the installer. Thanks again for the info.

Comment: You can download the SDKs for free.  I don't know if they will install without Studio or if you might be able to install against Express maybe.  You might also try finding a VS2008 eval version and install against it, then install the SDKs.